# How to filter based on specific material numbers within a table using SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to return certain information for a specific group of material #s and am having a hard time getting successful results.

I'm able to get it to work with one material but need to do it for around 1,000 materials and haven't been able to find an easy way to do it for multiple values at once. Any advice would be appreciated I am a big time rookie at SQL. Thanks in advance.

This is what I've been using so far:

```
SELECT        tblZMMGPNXREF.*
FROM            tblZMMGPNXREF
where ZLPN = 'B85777'
```

Comment: You need dynamic SQL. Please provide additional details. For example, where do these 1000 material values come from, are they specific values stored in a flat file, table etc. Please provide table structure as well.

Comment: Either `where ZLPN in ( 'B85777', 'M10012', 'U75147', ...)`, or store the 1000 values in a separate (temporary) table and `join`.